# Context for ArrayAdapter in Fragment Class

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i'm trying to implement a search bar for a listView in a Fragment for Android. I got it working in an activity, but now i´ll need to make it work in a fragment. Here's my code:

```
public class AboFragment extends Fragment {

String [] items;
ArrayList<String> listItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listView;
EditText editText;

public AboFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_abo, container, false);
    listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    editText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textsearch);
    initList();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.toString().equals("")){
                initList();
            }
            else{
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    Button dealerActivity = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_dealer);
    dealerActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent startDealer = new Intent(getActivity(), DealerActivity.class);
            startActivity(startDealer);

        }
    });
    return v;
}

public void initList(){
    items = new String[]{"Canada", "China", "Japan", "USA"};
    listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.textitem, listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
    for(String item:items){
        if(!item.contains(textToSearch)){
            listItems.remove(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

The problem lies in the initList() method, where i'm trying to initialize the adapter for my arraylist but I'm not sure how to fix it. It doesn't accept "this". I also tried "getContext" with no success. Error message is "cannot resolve constructor".
If i run the app with "getActivity" as context it doesn't crash but the search bar isn't there as well.

Comment: no, no, no, filtering in adapters is done by calling `adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint)`, there are hundreds of examples at SO and on the web as well

Comment: If you'd like to ask about the missing search bar, then ask about that, not the unrelated errors

Answer (score 7):

> It doesn't accept "this".

`this` is a `Fragment`. [`Fragment` does not inherit from `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

> I also tried "getContext" with no success.

[`Fragment` does not have a `getContext()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

Use `getActivity()` to get an instance of the hosting `Activity`. `Activity` inherits from `Context`.

> but the search bar isn't there as well.

That is some separate problem, such as with your layout. It has nothing to do with the parameter that you are passing to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `v.getContext()` from (`View v = inflater.inflate(...)`) and pass it to your `initList()` method as `initList(Context context)` instead of `getActivity()` which can cause two problems:

1) you can't be sure that `getActivity()` won't be null in `onCreateView(..)`, so if you want to use `getActivity()` then set up your array adapter in `onActivityCreated(..)`

2) it can cause a memory leak in case you use setRetainInstance(true) in your fragment because it won't be able to garbage collect activity instance on orientation change

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_panneau, container, false)
    val listItem = mutableListOf("Julien", "Gabriel","Henok","Audrey","Sandra","Hervé","Gargarine")
    val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
   arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(  v.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,listItem)
    v.listView_panneau.adapter = arrayAdapter

    return v
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).